# MongoDB write order Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

If I had a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  collection.updateOne(query, {
    $set: {
      number: i
    }
  });
}
```

would I be guaranteed that the last update sent would be the one stored in the database, or is there a chance that one or more of the updates may arrive out of order?

If updates can arrive out of the order in which they are sent, is there a way to guarantee that the updates arrive in order without waiting for a response from the database between sending each one (would have to be able to work within a synchronous loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would I be guaranteed that the last update sent would be the one stored in the database

no, not the way you have written this code.

> is there a way to guarantee that the updates arrive in order without waiting for a response from the database between sending each one (would have to be able to work within a synchronous loop).

again, no. not without using a callback to wait for the operation to complete before moving on to the next one.

your best option is to use an asynchronous iteration, but delay iterating to the next item until the previous one completes.

i've got a blog post about [serially iterating an array, asynchronously](http://derickbailey.com/2015/03/12/serially-iterating-an-array-asynchronously/), which will show you how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want guaranteed order, use [Bulk](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/#Bulk) operations with [initializeorderedbulkop](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp/#db-collection-initializeorderedbulkop)

Example:

```
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

for(var i=0;i <= 100; i++){
    bulk.find( { ... } ).updateOne(
       {
          $set:{number:1}   
       }
    );
}

bulk.execute();
```

Comment: oh, nice! didn't know about that. will have to do that next time i need this. :)

Comment: In my case they would have to be separate operations, but in some circumstances performed at speeds as if they were in a loop. Good to know this exists though.

Comment: bulk accepts all kind of operations and will execute in order of they appear in bulk. See documentation.